# WooCommerce - How to assign category to user/user-role (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to build a WooCommerce B2B shop with products which are specific to customers/ user roles. E.g. I have some products in a category named "ABC Shop" and an user role named "ABC Shop". I want that only users with the role "ABC Shop" can see products in this category.

Furthermore, I would like to have "normal" categories (which are not user-specific) like "T-shirts", "Pants" and so on. Lets say I do put "T-shirt 1" into categories "ABC Shop" and "T-shirts". Users with the role "ABC Shop" should see this product in "T-shirts"-category.

In short: I would like to build custom shops which are user-role specific.

I prefer solutions with plugins rather than custom code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood, you need vendors for your website products.

WooCommerce already have such a [plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-vendors/).